# it's possible to create a trigger to move data between databases in postgresql?

Tags: database, postgresql, triggers

I will try to simplify my problem:
let's say that I have 2 databases, let's call them DBA and DBB,

I have this table on DBA

```
shopping
id - name - amount
```

and on my DBB I have this other table:

```
shopping_hist
id - name - amount
```

every end of the month, I generate a dump from table shopping on DBA and copy its data
on table shopping_hist on DBB, it's possible to create a trigger that for every insert on Shopping, it will also make an insert on Shopping_hist, since they are not even on the same database?

I know that if they were on the same database, even if not on the same schema, it would be possible, but I'm not finding anything to automate this when it's for distinct databases

Comment: Foreign data wrappers / dblink probably can do that

Comment: you can also use logical replication to replicate the table from one database to the other.